# Regex match any IP not in internal range

Tags: regex, vba

I am currently writing an excel macro and I am having some real troubles with my specific requirement.

I need to loop through cells and find any ip addresses which are not in the private ranges,

```
10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255
172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255
192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255
```

The code i am using:

```
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With RE
    .MultiLine = False
    .Global = False
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = ??
End With
```

Not having any issues with the VBA code, just with the pattern.

Would really love a regexp guru to help!

Cell is formatted like this for example:

```
192.168.1.1 (subnet name), 203.134.56.7 (third party unknown), 10.0.0.0/8 (voice subnet), 10.1.1.5 (voice server), 56.8.0.0/16 (google)
```

As for the comment below, that is why I am looking for a regex solution if there is one as it means i can just run it over a cell and it should still find a third party IP as apposed to splitting into an array, and running each ip through a function.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: what is your exact data layout? Am easier way may be to extract the IP address into 4 columns, then test each portion for lying within the range

Answer (score 0):

The following regex code should help you out. If a valid IP address is input, it will match ones not in the private range. It does not however, determine if IP address is valid (it may, for example, match 192.168.864.543.) It could be altered to work that out, but it's more difficult since regex's work on strings rather than numbers.

```
10\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|172.([1][6-9]|[2][0-9]|[3][0-1])\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|192.168\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}
```

That said, as a comment suggested, regular expressions may not be the best way to solve this problem. Above is a way you could do it with regular expressions if you want to use them, but as mentioned there are limitations.

Comment: It certainly is not that a bad job if the IP is represented in hexadecimal form, or even better if it is shown in binary form.

Comment: But that still doesn't cover IPv6. :-)

Comment: From what i can see this seems to match a private IP, so if a match is not found, i would know the cell has an external IP address. The problem i have however is that the cell may have multiple IP addresses' in it. So i really need to highlight only if it has a external IP address rather than the method mentioned above. Anyone have a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you give an example of exactly how each cell is formatted?

Comment: How could you add a subnet restriction x.x.x.x/xx